# Using replace in different parts of the same string

Tags: java

I have a situation here, I have a `String` and I must to replace this `<br>` to `<br />`. To do it I can use replace or replace all, but some parts of the text I have `<br style='font-size: 14px;'> <a><a/>` and I need replace to `<br style='font-size: 14px;' /> <a><a/>` and any others similar situations in the same string;

IN

```
"<br> text here <br/> text here <br> text here <br style='font-size: 14px;'> <a><a/>"
```

EXPECTED OUT

```
"<br /> text here <br /> text here <br /> text here <br style='font-size: 14px;' /> <a><a/>"
```

Can you help me with this simple logic? replace only `<br` cases

Comment: Perhaps the `replaceAll` method might be of help?

Comment: you need to use regexp to perform replace of your second example if you do not want to write an HTML paresre

Comment: Please bear in mind that using regexps for html may be dangerous as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help. This is a regex code possibility:

```
package com.jesperancinha.string;

public class StringReplaceBr {

    public static  String closeBrTags(String a){
        return a.replaceAll("<br(\\/)?([a-zA-z0-9='-:; \"]*)>", "<br$2 />");
    }
}
```

And this is the unit test to check it up:

```
package com.jesperancinha.string;


import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class StringReplaceBrTest {


    @Test
    void closeSingleAlreadyClosed() {
        assertThat(StringReplaceBr.closeBrTags("<br/>"))
                .isEqualTo("<br />");
    }

    @Test
    void closeSingleNotClosed() {
        assertThat(StringReplaceBr.closeBrTags("<br>"))
                .isEqualTo("<br />");
    }

    @Test
    void closeSingleMixedNotClosed() {
        assertThat(StringReplaceBr.closeBrTags("<br style=\"\" somethingElse=''>"))
                .isEqualTo("<br style=\"\" somethingElse='' />");
    }

    @Test
    void closeBrTags() {
        assertThat(StringReplaceBr.closeBrTags("<br> text here <br/> text here <br> text here <br style='font-size: 14px;'> <a><a/>"))
                .isEqualTo("<br /> text here <br /> text here <br /> text here <br style='font-size: 14px;' /> <a><a/>");
    }

    @Test
    void closeBrTagsDoubleQuotes() {
        assertThat(StringReplaceBr.closeBrTags("<br> text here <br/> text here <br> text here <br style=\"font-size: 14px;\"> <a><a/>"))
                .isEqualTo("<br /> text here <br /> text here <br /> text here <br style=\"font-size: 14px;\" /> <a><a/>");
    }

    @Test
    void closeBrSmall() {
        assertThat(StringReplaceBr.closeBrTags("<br/> <br> <br/> <a><a/> <br wow=''>"))
                .isEqualTo("<br /> <br /> <br /> <a><a/> <br wow='' />");
    }

}
```

Comment: Extra points for including a unit test. I would expand that unit test with a few more cases, though.

Comment: I'd add " in case <br style="something"> occurs

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz thank you so much for your comment and your pointers. I have just expanded the unit tests :)

Comment: @wojteo thank you too for your comment and pointers. I have just added support with double quotes. :)